# Actualizar <div> cada X segundos

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Necesito una funcion para recargar un  cada X segundos pues el valor de la BBDD puede cambiar.
Tengo lo siguiente, pero no me actualiza el valor. Que me falla?

div:

```
<div id="results">valor a cargar</div>
```

El script:

```
function sendRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/count.php",
        success: 
          function(result){
           $('#results').text(result);
           setTimeout(function(){
          sendRequest();
           }, 3000);
        }});
});
```

y el codigo en "ajax/count.php" me devuelve el total de valores de una tabla:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['TOTAL'];        
}
```

Comment: ¿Está seguro que retorna correctamente el valor de su llamada Ajax? Puede que el error esté en PHP :3:)

Comment: tampoco con .html. El php funciona pues me da un valor de 4: http://176.58.105.104/form/ajax/count.php

Comment: No tiene errores de sintaxis en consola ? al parecer  le sobra un cierre al final , debería terminar en `}`  la función más no es `});`

Comment: en consola no me aparecen errores. Ni en el index.php ni en el ajax.php

Comment: carga la pagina y pon esto en la consola :
$('#results').load('ajax/count.php')

Comment: agregue comentarios en el code de la respuesta para clarificar porque timeout y no interval y como hacer la primer peticion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un par de asuntos a considerar:

1) si usas interval en una llamada asíncrona, puede darse el caso de que se vuelva a pedir algo antes de que llegue la respuesta anterior

2) la versión de jquery que usas debe ser la min y no la slim

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
```

en vez de

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js">
```

código funcional, nótese que uso el oncomplete para lanzar la nueva petición

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>ajaxreload</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function sendRequest(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/count.php",
    success:
      function(result){ 
/* si es success mostramos resultados */
       $('#results').text(result);
    },
    complete: function() { 
/* solo una vez que la petición se completa (success o no success) 
   pedimos una nueva petición en 3 segundos */
       setTimeout(function(){
         sendRequest();
       }, 3000);
      }
    });
  };

/* primera petición que echa a andar la maquinaria */
$(function() {
    sendRequest();
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: si. uso la min. El problema sigue.. no me actualiza el valor que hay en el php

Comment: no hay error de consola? es en el mismo dominio/ip?

Comment: si. el ajax.php es: http://176.58.105.104/form/ajax/count.php y el index: http://176.58.105.104/form

Comment: ok, lo que veo en la pagina form es que el count esta siendo llamado varias veces por segundo, debido a esto el navegador puede estar esperando a actualizar el valor. (luego de 25 segundos te crashea el php y da error 500)

Comment: y como cargo una primera vez y luego que actualice si hay un nuevo valor?

Comment: en el ejemplo que di, el primero es llamado en las ultimas 4 lineas, los subsiguientes se llaman cuanto la operacion (independientemente de si es success) es complete, y con un timeout para que sea una sola vez por cada peticion

Comment: añadido este trozo, pero no carga a la primera...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75318/discussion-between-alo-malbarez-and-guif-if).

Answer (score 1):

Usa setInterval en lugar de setTimeout ya que setTimeout lo que hará es esperar tres segundos y después ejecutarse.

setInterval se estara ejecutando cada tres segundos en tu caso.

Espero te sirva

```js
function sendRequest() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/count.php",
    success: function(result) {
      $('#results').text(result);
    }
  });
});

setInterval(function(){ 
   sendRequest();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="results">valor a cargar</div>
```